# Are there any packages suited for making wedding invitations?

Tags: document-classes

I'm getting married this coming winter, and it's about time to think about wedding invitations. Are their any document classes or packages suitable for this purpose?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

There's [`gcard`](http://ctan.org/pkg/gcard), intended for typesetting greeting cards with front and back cover and inside left and right page. All is arranged on a sheet to be folded.

See also [Creating Leaflets and Greeting Cards](http://texcatalogue.ctan.org/bytopic.html#leaflets) in the TeX Catalogue.