# Designing a fancy Wedding invitation card

Tags: cards

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Are there any packages suited for making wedding invitations?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1251/are-there-any-packages-suited-for-making-wedding-invitations)

i m very very new on working with latex but i am thoroughly impressed by it output and quality.
Now my problem or query is that i need to design a fancy invitation card for my brother's wedding and reception, but i do not know how to :(

I would appreciate if someone can help me with that.

Required information to be put in the invitation -

- Invitation message,
- Groom's Parents Name,
- Groom's Name,
- Bride's Name,
- Date of Marriage,
- Venue,
- concluding note or message

Comment: We accept Visa and Paypal :P Welcome to LaTeX! [welcome to TeX.sx](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx). In its current form, your question might not receive many answers. Please take a look at the [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask)-page and try to improve your question according to the guidance found there. This may require you to show some effort on your part in terms of attempting a solution. If you have questions about what to do or if you don't quite understand what this means, please ask for clarification.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Usually, we don't put a greeting or a "thank you" in our posts. While this might seem strange at first, it is not a sign of lack of politeness, but rather part of our trying to keep everything very concise. Upvoting is the preferred way here to say "thank you" to users who helped you.

Comment: Probably this link can help: http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/46406/10898

Comment: I assume that the only things you are having an issue with is the "fancy" part of the question. Perhaps [Package for certificates](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/46406), [Does anybody know a good source of (free) ornaments, decorations, frames, backgrounds etc.?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/41159), [Free ornaments font](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/10941) will get you started, and then you can post a question about a specific problem you are having.

Comment: At least related: [Are there any packages suited for making wedding invitations?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1251/are-there-any-packages-suited-for-making-wedding-invitations)